# How do I specify X, Y, Width and Height in order to crop in Photoshop?

Tags: crop, photoshop

In Adobe Fireworks you were always able to numerically specify the X and Y coordinates, width, and height of the area you want to crop - where is this option in Photoshop?

Apologies if I'm being thick - I'm still pretty new to Photoshop!

I need to be able to do this through the Photoshop editor as opposed to through script.

Comment: This is off topic for this site.  You're probably better of checking out some of the other stack exchange sites - you'll get better answers.  Super User maybe?

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice! I'll head on over there in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find it in Info pallet in window/Info

also there is other information like color of the pixel youre pointing.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This does give me the information I'm interested in, but it doesn't let me specify the coordinates, width, or height - and this is what I need to be able to do.

Comment: Yes it just shows the position but if you want to crop it with a specified size you can use crop tool top menu bar to specify width and height in px or cm or mm and also you can use Canvas Size from image menu....

to crop it from an exact x and y location first you change canvas size from top right with (OldWidth - X) and (OldHeight - y) and then  change canvas size with newWidth and newHeight from bottom left....any way there is no tool to specify x and y position you want to crop from.

Comment: @davidr360 If my answer solved your problem, please click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer. This way, other people know that the problem is solved. As a bonus you'll receive some rep-points and a badge;)

Comment: your answer seems to be the closest thing I have to a solution, thank you! The menu bar at the top of the crop menu actually seems to refer to the aspect ratio of the crop, and not the pixel size of the crop itself. It's a shame Adobe didn't include the proper functionality for such a basic feature! Thanks again for your response.

Comment: if you put px after your number in the box the measurement unit will be pixels, there would be more options like mm, cm, in, and so on

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rectangle mark tool to mark the area you want to crop, then go to Image -> Crop

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm not too sure what you mean by rectangle mark tool. I know you can select an area to crop by dragging a box around it using the crop tool, but this is not what I'm after - I need to be able to manually type the X, Y, Width, and Height for the crop